# Why are some players not auctionable in Madden 2015?

Tags: madden-15

What causes some players in Madden 15 to be "Not Auctionable", but others can be auctioned?

I looked at the auction house and some of the players that i have and cannot auction other people can auction just fine. Is it just random when you get them from the packs?

Comment: Did you get them from gift and/or promotion packs?

Comment: Most are from the starter pack i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Players (or anything else, really) obtained from "promotional" packs (for example, the starter pack you get when you first begin your *Ultimate Team* or free gifts from various promotions) will not be eligible for auction and will also, IIRC, not provide any coins when you quick sell them.